# Nano text editor - How to bring back on the syntax coloring?

Tags: colors, nano

I am using the Nano text editor.

Before, there was color on every command I typed, but now I don't know what buttons I pressed as there are no more colors.

How to bring back on the syntax coloring?

[image: screen of my assignment]

Answer (score 1):

You probably pressed <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, that <kbd>Meta</kbd> usually is <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>, so <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>.

Press it again to undo the change.

---

You can also force colors temporarily with; taken from the `--help`:

> ```
>  -Y <name>    --syntax=<name>     Syntax definition to use for coloring
> ```

Usage:

```
nano -Y sh assign
```

---

Also, implicitly, the file must be marked executable in order for the syntax coloring to come up automatically, so just a quick check:

```
ls -l assign
```